# Magento REST API Questions

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, rest-api

I am trying to figure out how to achieve the following via the Magento REST API:

1. Create a shipment (to fulfill an order's line items)
2. Void a shipment
3. Add or update the order notes

Can you confirm if this can be done and/or how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

See here for info:http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html

As you can see there is no support via REST for shipment processing, and you can only view order comments, not change.